# XMonad: start program floating based on window title

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I use this truly excellent Firefox add-on: https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext/
Hit `ctrl-e` to edit any textarea in Vim.

However vim starts up tiled. My browser workspaces are single-window tabbed, so a fullscreen editor is overkill. Here's what I tried to make it start as a floating window:

```hs
    -- This works, but matches any vim instance, not just itsalltext instances:
    -- , className =? "Gvim" --> doFloat
    -- This does nothing:
    , fmap (isInfixOf "itsalltext") title --> doFloat
```

`xprop` shows this for the window that is created:

```
    WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gvim", "Gvim"
    WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "mail.google.com.3c1b1v2w21.txt (~/.mozilla/firefox/3waevusx.default/itsalltext) - GVIM1"
    _NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "mail.google.com.3c1b1v2w21.txt (~/.mozilla/firefox/3waevusx.default/itsalltext) - GVIM1"
    WM_NAME(STRING) = "mail.google.com.3c1b1v2w21.txt (~/.mozilla/firefox/3waevusx.default/itsalltext) - GVIM1"
    _NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "mail.google.com.3c1b1v2w21.txt (~/.mozilla/firefox/3waevusx.default/itsalltext) - GVIM1"
```

Bonus question: `doFloat` works, but I'd really like to specify *how* to float. For scratchpads, this works:

```hs
customFloating $ W.RationalRect (1/6) (1/6) (2/3) (2/3)
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use `customFloating` for a window that's not a scratchpad.

Comment: How about `doRectFloat (W.RationalRect (1/6) (1/6) (2/3) (2/3))` ?