# xmonad: toggle a window between floating and tiled

Tags: xmonad

Sometimes I launch a window tiled. Maybe as a scratchpad (using [NamedScratchpad](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-NamedScratchpad.html)) or as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973641/xmonad-start-program-floating-based-on-window-title).

Now I want to be able to zoom (either fullscreen or tile) this floating window, and then toggle back to the previous tiled size & position.

What is a good way to accomplish that?

Also, if I hit the hotkey for a scratchpad, I want it to open according to the specification in my config file --- not according to the current state (e.g. tiled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your (zooming) question correctly, [`XMonad.Layout.Maximize`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Maximize.html) provides what you're looking for.
Please note that `maximize` affects the naming of your Layout - if you use `XMonad.Layout.Named` you may want to define the name before `maximize` like

```
myLayout = named "myName"
           $ maximize
           $ someLayout
```

with a keybinding like

```
((modm, xK_backslash), withFocused (sendMessage . maximizeRestore))
```

described in the linked documentation.

Currently this module maximizes not completely, but leaves a bit of border. If it bugs you, you can modify the module and place your version at `~/.xmonad/lib/modifiedMaximize` from where you can import it with

```
import modifiedMaximize
```

in your `xmonad.hs`.