# define an xmonad keymap to set doFullFloat on current window

Tags: xmonad

I want to do something like this from the standard maps:

```
, ((modMask,     xK_t     ), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)
```

But the opposite ie a bit like:

```
, ((modMask,     xK_t     ), withFocused $ windows . W.doFullFloat)
```

I get some way with:

```
, ((modMask,     xK_t     ), withFocused $ float)
```

But that doesnt maximise it - it would to be

```
, ((modMask,     xK_t     ), do
   withFocused $ float
   [SOMETHING TO MAXIMISE WINDOW]
)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just hitting `M-SPC` a few times so the layout is full?

Comment: Yes... I really just want to be able to full screen a window and back again quickly.

Just found http://superuser.com/a/238454 and MultiToggle which does the job really nicely!

Answer (score 2):

The [`float` function from XMonad.StackSet](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-StackSet.html#v:float) takes a window and a rectangle.

With `import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W` :

```
((modm, xK_f), withFocused $ windows . (flip W.float $ W.RationalRect 0 0 1 1)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly orthogonal answer but this answer does what I actually want - just not how I had planned to it: [Using MultiToggle](https://superuser.com/a/238454)

This is the magic module: [MultiToggle](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-MultiToggle.html)

And I did it by modifying my layouts to inject

```
id . smartBorders . mkToggle (NOBORDERS ?? FULL ?? EOT)
```

before the list of layouts and then added a keymap

```
, ((modMask, xK_w ), sendMessage $ LMT.Toggle FULL)
```

If anyone can give an answer to my original question/method, I'll vote it as the correct answer! Thanks.

Another alternative seems to be provided [Layout.Maximise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566408/75528)